# RestClient Elastic Search external host

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am trying to hit an external URL ES server using Java Springboot.

The corresponding cURL is:

```
curl -XGET 'xyz.elasticsearch.abc.consul:9200/data/values/_search?' -d '{"query"
:{"bool":{"must":{"match":{"_type__s":"filter-variable"}}}}}'
```

```
            RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
                    RestClient.builder(
                            new HttpHost("xyz.elasticsearch.abc.consul", 9200, "http")));
            SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("data");
            SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
            searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("_type__s", "filter-variable"));
            searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
            SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
            SearchHits hits = searchResponse.getHits();
            SearchHit[] searchHits = hits.getHits();
            for (SearchHit hit : searchHits) {
                Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = hit.getSourceAsMap();
                System.out.println("name  "+ sourceAsMap.get("name"));
            }
            client.close();
```

With this I end up receiving `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)` while curl still works in the same machine. Any help would be great.

Comment: Havent figured how to use the Client yet, but a simple alternative is to use RestTemplate to make requests. Pass the full URL all the way to _search? and the query as the payload and it works just fine. Can use Gson to handle Json responses if needed.

Comment: There are elasticsearch libraries for Java, wouldnt those help?

Comment: by libraries I hope you mean the API. I tried them and I cant get them to work. @Smit